# Why do the info lines get printed when importing kivy in python?

Tags: python, import, kivy, python-internals

When I import `kivy` in python:

```
>>> import kivy
```

The following three debug lines get printed:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record Log in C:\Users\usrname\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-04-07_50.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

I know this is rather intended than an error, but I'd like to suppress this output. I have read the file `kivy\__init__.py` and figured out that the lines get printed when following line is executed:

```
from kivy.compat import PY2
```

So I have read `kivy\compat.py` too, which isn't even a big file (102 lines), but I still can't see why the debug lines get printed.

I've executed *every single line* (including docstrings and comments) of the file in the python console and couldn't reproduce it.

Can somebody explain this to me? I assume that this is something internal and is only possible because I installed it with pip but actually I have no clue what's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is generated by the [`kivy.logger` module](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/9f64f5e24240cbf7e2cd34315d08131fd31ec822/kivy/logger.py), which simply uses the standard [Python `logger` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html).

The module adds a logger to output to the console, unless the `KIVY_NO_CONSOLELOG` environment variable has been set:

```
if 'KIVY_NO_CONSOLELOG' not in os.environ:
    # ...
    formatter = ColoredFormatter(color_fmt, use_color=use_color)
    console = ConsoleHandler()
    console.setFormatter(formatter)
    Logger.addHandler(console)
```

From that point on, logged messages are printed out to your console.

It is not the `kivy.compat` module that triggers all this; when importing a module inside a package, Python will always make sure that the package itself is loaded first. Thus `import kivy.compat` will trigger an import of `kivy` itself if not already loaded.

It is `kivy/__init__.py` that outputs the first log message:

```
if RELEASE:
    Logger.info('Kivy: v%s' % (__version__))
```

but the `kivy.logger.FileHandler` object that is also configured (unless `KIVY_NO_FILELOG` is set in the environment) runs extra code when first used and inserts `Logger.info('Logger: Record log in %s' % filename)` before the `Kivy: v<version>` message is handled. Finally, `kivy/__init__.py` executes `Logger.info('Python: v{}'.format(sys.version))` to output the Python version info.

Comment: this makes sense since the `kivy.logger` module is imported by `kivy\__init__.py`. However, the debug lines get also printed when I directly `>>> import kivy.compat` though this module doesn't import `kivy.logger` which looks really strange to me

Comment: Python imports `kivy` *first* for any name within the package, so importing `kivy.compat` will also see `kivy/__init__.py` loaded first.